# Is it possible predict the oxidizing/reducing nature of a compound?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

I have recently begun with Inorganic Chemistry and am finding it totally difficult to understand things (I am trying to minimize memorization and approach logically).

One of the things I am having problems with is understanding oxidizing and reducing agents. 
Given a compound(and a few other necessary conditions in some cases), can I predict whether the compound will behave as a reducing or an oxidizing agent? 
Well obviously if there is any such rule, there will be exceptions. But is there anything as such to reason out a few statements and take me partly towards the answer?

For example I have begun with Group 1 and the book says at some point that peroxides and superoxides of alkali metals act as strong oxidizing agents, group 1 hydrides are powerful reducing agents etc. Well I find it difficult to understand these statements and my book offers no explanation.

Answer (score 4):

You may or may not be familiar with the concepts of [electronegativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronegativity) and [oxidation states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxidation_state), but ultimately here is the rule of thumb you seek. If your compound contains highly electronegative elements **not** in their most negative oxidation state, expect it to be an oxidizer. If it contains elements with low electronegativity which are **not** in their most positive oxidation state, expect it to manifest at least some reducing properties.

On top of that, just like you anticipated, there is a whole lot of exceptions and subtleties which together constitute the magnificent field of elementary inorganic chemistry.

Comment: fortunately I do know about basics such as Electronegativity and Ox. states and redox potential and similar things.It would be great if you had a source or a link somewhere on the internet so that I could read and know more about it.

Comment: Well, if you are studying inorganic chemistry now, I guess you'll stumble upon a lot of links, sources, and facts to consider.